# Hibernate criteria returns empty result

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I want to retrieve data from the database (Oracle) using Hibernate.

I want to select all columns from a view. The view has no primary key, so I used composite key in the Hibernate-mapping.

Firstly my class:

```
public class MyBean implements Serializable {
    private MyBeanId compId;
    private String col1;
    private String col2;
    // getters and setters
}
```

Where the MyBeanId class:

```
public class MyBeanId implements Serializable {
    private int id1;
    private int id2;
    // getters and setters, hashCode and equals
}
```

The Hibernate mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="com.mypackage">
<class name="MyBean" table="MY_TABLE">
    <composite-id name="compId" class="MyBeanId ">
        <key-property column="COL_ID1" name="id1" type="int"/>
        <key-property column="COL_ID2" name="id2" type="int"/>

    </composite-id>
    <property name="col1" type="string">
        <column name="COL1" />
    </property>
    <property name="col2" type="string">
        <column name="COL2" />
    </property>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

My DAO (MyBeanManagerImpl):

```
public List<MyBean> getMyBeans(Session session) {

    try {
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(MyBean.class);
        List<MyBean> list = criteria.list();
        System.out.println(list.toString());
        return list;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}
```

And my table MY_TABLE:

```
ID1,ID2,COL1,COL2
1,2,"a","b"
3,2,"c","d"
```

The result is an empty list. I've verified there's data in my table. When I use other managers in my service, there's no problem getting the result so there's no problem with the session.

There's no Exception thrown at all, so it is strange it doesn't get any result.

Comment: How does your db look like?

Comment: Why do you have 'cutter'     <property name="cutter" type="string">
        <column name="COL2" />
    </property> for the property col2?

Comment: @ŁukaszRzeszotarski Sorry, I've forgotten to change that when I paste my code

Comment: Do you use any framework like spring where you configure session factory for instance?

Comment: Alternatively did you added mapping-resource entry for the new class/mapping to hibernate-configuration?

Comment: @ŁukaszRzeszotarski I'm using Struts and I didn't added mapping-resource entry to hibernate-configuration. Could you tell me where should I add it? Because I'm doing this following examples elsewhere in a big project, and I can't find such an example. Many thanks!

Comment: Can you paste your hibernate.cfg.xml file or sth similar then Ill extend my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add mapping-resource entry for the new mapping in yours hibernate-configuration -> session factory configuration like you have for other already mapped classes.

See the link https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Web_Platform/5/html/Hibernate_Core_Reference_Guide/tutorial.html#tutorial-firstapp-configuration Chapter 'Hibernate configuration' there you have example of hibernate.cfg.xml. You need to add <mapping-resouce ... entry